# Best way to order data by association value in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Trying to order all rows of a model for an ordering filter with react on the front, I have encountered this problem.

For example if I have "rooms" and each reservation having many products, having each product different prices, I came up with this way of ordering the rooms by the their respective lowest valued product or the highest:

```
 scope :high_price, lambda {   joins(:products).group('rooms.id').order('max(products.week_price) DESC') }

  scope :low_price, lambda {  joins(:products).group('rooms.id').order('min(products.week_price) ASC') }
```

The problem comes when, if I save this into an instance variable:

```
@ordered_rooms = Room.low_price
```

And then I try to manipulate given instance, I will run into this issue:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "products.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

- I found some explanation of the problem [here](https://tomkadwill.com/2017/12/18/counting-or-sorting-by-an-association-in-a-rails-sql-query.html), but then my doubt would be how to do this queries so this error does not come up?

---

I found that, if the metric I was looking for, would be the number of products by room, it would be easier to look up with:

```
  scope :most_products, lambda {  order('products_count DESC') }
```

adding this relation into product:

```
  belongs_to :room, required: false, counter_cache: true
```

would it be possible to define this kind of cache for other metrics, or how should I go about these queries?